# Is it possible to cool down air with warm water?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, evaporation, cooling

Is there some condition in wich the water evaporation can cool down the air even if the water is hotter than the air?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly; an evaporative cooler(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler), also called a water cooler or swamp cooler, cools air by the process of evaporating water. As liquid water evaporates, it becomes much cooler. So even if the liquid water is warmer than the air, the vapor could still be cooler than the air.